# Insert to database when button is click

Tags: php, database, button, insert

I have a button when click it will insert the statement to the database however even without clicking the button the insert statement is already run .why?

```
<?php
header('P3P: CP="NOI ADM DEV PSAi COM NAV OUR OTRo STP IND DEM"');
include_once 'mysqli.connect.php';
include_once 'fbmain.php';

if($me){
    $fbid= $facebook->api('/me');
    $fbme = $fbid['id'];
    $fbName = $fbid['name'] ;  
    $fbEmail = $fbid['email'];
}
    if (isset($_POST)){
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO members (fbId, name, email) values ('$fbme', '$fbName', '$fbEmail')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
?>
<html>
<form action="" method="post">
    <input type="image" src="../images/buy.png" name="submit" width="60"height="30" />
</form>
</html>
```

Comment: This is more suited for ajax than a form submit.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define what is submitted ? Try this:

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    //Query or something 
}
```

This code say if some input is named = submit is set (clicked/Posted) then query will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

check if `$_POST` is not `empty()` like this

```
if (!empty($_POST)){
        mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO members (fbId, name, email) values ('$fbme', '$fbName', '$fbEmail')") or die(mysql_error());
    }
```

Comment: the problem still occurs everytime the page refreshes it enters to database.

Comment: print the `$_POST` variable inside `if` statement and check the values

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    mysqli_query($mysqli, "INSERT INTO members (fbId, name, email) 
values ('$fbme', '$fbName', '$fbEmail')") or die(mysql_error());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to be more specific about which key you check for the existence of, as your Facebook app is always fetched via the POST method, as this is how Facebook injects signed requests.

Odd I know, but that's Facebook for you.